# How do I make my query search using different conditions?

Tags: oracle

I have a query which retrieves student enrolments on an Activity Template, which is the child of a Module. Some of the Activity Templates are orphaned (i.e. have no Module parent on the student's enrolment) and I want to identify Activity Templates which are orphaned BUT where the student is enrolled on the Module parent so I can re-link them. The long query I have thus far is shown below and it works for the most part, it is also retrieving orphaned Activity Templates which do not have a Module Parent on the student's enrolment;

```
--this first part looks for Activity Template enrolments for a student

    select 
    pers.p_surname
    ,pers.p_forenames
    ,s_studentreference
    ,e_id
    ,e_start
    ,e_end
    ,e_parent
    ,e_student
    ,e_module
    ,e_reference
    ,e_name
    ,e_type
    from capd_moduleenrolment, capd_student, capd_person pers
    where e_type='ACTTMPL'
    and e_start>='01-Sep-2019'
    and e_student = s_id
    and pers.p_id = s_id
    and e_parent not in --this clause then looks for that enrolment whose parent does not exist in the following query which retrieves Activity Template enrolments which have a parent

    --this sub-query then retrieves Activity Templates with a parent Module enrolment on the student's record

        (select 
        module.e_id 
        from capd_moduleenrolment template
        ,capd_student
        ,capd_moduleenrolment module
        where template.e_type='ACTTMPL'
        and module.e_type='MOD'
        and template.e_start>='01-Sep-2019'
        and template.e_student = s_id
        and template.e_parent = module.e_id)

--this part of the query below ensures that only the orphaned Activity Template enrolments which are retrieved have a similar reference to the Module enrolment i.e. I trimmed the Module reference so that the query checks the Module reference (before the session code like 15PMUH026-A19/20) against the Activity Template (before the underscore like 15PMUH026_L1) to ensure the student is enrolled on the Module from which the Template has been unlinked.

    and SUBSTR (e_reference, 1, INSTR (e_reference, '_') - 1) in

    (select SUBSTR(e_reference, 0, LENGTH(e_reference) - 7)
    from 
    capd_student stud
    ,capd_moduleenrolment moduenrol
    WHERE moduenrol.e_student = stud.s_id
    AND moduenrol.e_start >='01-Sep-2019'
    and MODUenrol.e_status='L'
    and moduenrol.e_type='MOD')

    order by p_surname
```

Please note that the example of the Module I have provided is 15PMUH026-A19/20 and the sessions code is 'A19/20) highlighting this academic year. The child Activity Template for this Module would therefore be 15PMUH026_L1.

So in a nutshell, I need my query to give me a list of Activity Templates on which a student is enrolled (15PMUH026_L1 in this case) but the Activity Template is not linked to parent Module (15PMUH026-A19/20 in this case) BUT the student is enrolled on both. So essentially what the query should do is look for students enrolled on Activity Template 15PMUH026_L1 and also enrolled on it's parent Module 15PMUH026-A19/20 (the query looks for a match to see if the Activity Template reference before the underscore matches and Module enrolment before the session code (A19/20) where the template is not linked to the parent.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Best Regards,

Comment: This is a long query and some convoluted business rules. You are more likely to get a helpful and timely response if you provide (simplified) table structures, sample data and required output derived from that sample. Rewriting queries is hard work, and easy to get wrong; not everybody has time on their hands to write DDL and DML statements for your problem. Help us to help you.

Comment: Sounds to me like you also have a database design issue:  The two objects involved have a relationship, but the relationship is embedded in a substring of a set of columns which coincidentally have substrings that match, but (evidently) there is no real primary key/foreign key relationship.  You could probably formulate a query to work on the substrings or other pattern matching (e.g. regular expressions) but what if the string formats change, then the application is broken without the relationships being defined declaratively in the PK/FK relationships.